# Update a UDF where I know in advance the cells that will possibly change the result, but that are not direct parameters

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, automatic-update

I have a UDF that calculates the carry-over of growth over a year. That is for instance, at the second quarter of the year, the yearly growth rate if the growth in the third and fourth quarters is null. In this case, I would need the growth or the fourt quarters of the previous year and the two first quarters of the current year. [image]

This is not very hard to compute or to program. To be easily accessible, the people to whom it is destined have largely favoured that only the last observed point should be an input of the function. Other input is the number of quarters of observed data I have.  In this case it would be `CarryOver(C16,2)`

With this way of doing, if another past value changes, it does not update my UDF. I can force that by using `Application.Volatile` but first it does not seem to work if the value used is based on a formula that refers to another sheet. 
And more fundamentally, I can calculate in advance which cells will be used with the two inputs (cell of the last data, number of quarters I have, so in this case : `C11:C16`) so there might be a way to tell Excel to calculate this UDF each time one of the values in the implied cells change, which would be better that the `volatile` option. Is that doable ?

EDIT : the core of my UDF would be :

```
Public Function CarryOver(DerniereDonneeDure As Range, AcquisAuMoment_T_plus_X As Integer)


Dim Trim As Double
Trim = 100
        Ligne = DerniereDonneeDure.Row - AcquisAuMoment_T_plus_X + 1
        Colonne = DerniereDonneeDure.Column
        For i = -4 To -1
            Trim = Trim * (1 + Cells(Ligne + i, Colonne).Value)
            Ecoule = Ecoule + Trim
        Next
        For j = 0 To AcquisAuMoment_T_plus_X - 1
            Trim = Trim * (1 + Cells(Ligne + j, Colonne).Value)
            Encours = Encours + Trim
        Next
        For j = AcquisAuMoment_T_plus_X To 3
            Encours = Encours + Trim
        Next
    Acquis = Encours / Ecoule - 1

End Function
```

Comment: Can you provide the UDF? As it is, I'm not sure I understand your question. Based on the fact that no one else has commented in 17 hours, I will assume I am not the only one.

Comment: I added a simplified version

Comment: And all the `Cells(Ligne+i,Colonne)` for `i in -4 to AcquisAuMoment_T_plus_X - 1` impact my results, but only `Cells(Ligne+AcquisAuMoment_T_plus_X - 1,Colonne)` is passed as an argument

Comment: Can you fix that minimal example for it to be working? `Trim` will *always* equal zero in the present code, thus so will `Ecoule`, `Encours` and `Acquis`. I added `Application.volatile` and changed `Trim = Trim * (...` to `Trim = Trim + (...` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I corrected it, I had forgot the initialization that was in a different part of the code